# Removing the recurring dot using CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Is it possible to remove the dot before each of these fields using CSS? I cannot seem to find the ability to do so. thanks!

http://www.inksharks.com/kbca-registration/

Comment: ul { list-style: none; }  ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a background image added to each `li` element. You have to remove it by adding the following CSS

```
ul > li, .dark-icons ul > li {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try

`.gform_body ul li{list-style:none;}`

if above code does not work then
`.gform_body ul li{list-style:none !important;}`